# Intellij idea inspection profile updates

Tags: intellij-idea, code-inspection

I'd like to put the intellij's inspections xml file in our source control in order for all the devs to get the latest changes to it.

The problem is that after the initial import, idea isn't listening to changes to the inspections file. Thus, if someone updates the inspections file, the rest of the team needs to re-import it manually.

Any idea how to make the inspections update automatically based on some specific inspections file located in the project's folder?

Comment: How exactly did you put it in the source control? If you check in the files under .idea/inspectionProfiles, they will be updated automatically.

Comment: @yole - I don't have an `.idea` folder in the project root. I only have a `x.ipr` file.

Comment: I tried putting the inspections xml file under a newly created `.idea` folder but idea didn't show it as an option in the UI.

Comment: If you have an .ipr, then just check it in the version control - the project inspection profiles are stored there.

Comment: Where exactly? I tried putting it in the project root, but updates to the inspection file aren't taken by IDEA.

Comment: Check in the .ipr file.

Comment: But I don't want to check in the ipr file :(

Comment: If you want the inspection profiles to be updated, you need to store them as part of your project (.ipr or .idea) and add the project files to the version control. There is no other possibility.