# Copy of Java Project fails due to IntelliJ Inspection Profiles

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-inspections

**Context:** I am trying to copy my Java Project from one drive to another.

**Issue:** The copy stops, as it is unable to copy the Project_Default.xml file from .idea-> inspectionProfiles to destination. Only if I skip this, will I be able to copy the project. The file highlighted in the attached screenshot causes this issue.

**Research:** I referred to a couple of threads in this forum, but was unable to figure out. [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62338358/how-to-delete-inspection-profiles-in-intellij) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49514234/intellij-idea-inspection-profile-updates)

Query:

- I was able to manually copy that file to destination drive, but when I try to copy the whole project it fails at this file. Any reason why this happens?

Any inputs on what maybe causing this issue, will help me.

[image]

Comment: Windows, linux, mac? Looks like windows. Is this file in use or blocked by other app?

Comment: Its on windows. I closed IntelliJ, even tried with a restart, but the same issue.